# I cannot get the gam.check function to work

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I used the model below to predict marine survival in both SAS and R. The R code is below.

```
gam_mod<-gam(recruits/smolt ~ s(max, k = 6) + s(medB, k = 10),
weights = smolt, data = GAMdata, method = "REML", family = binomial("logit"))
```

However when I use gam.check(gam_mod) I get the error message below:

> Error in dm[, i] <- sort(residuals(object, type = type)) :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: You have a max argument, but that might be misinterpreted as an R function. You really shouldn't do that. But if you want a tested effort at debugging you should include a dataset that causes this. (Voting to close for lack of debugging details.)

Comment: Do you have any missing data values in your data set? Run `na.omit()` on your data and refit and then try `gam.check()`